# Migrating media files (documents only) to a fresh install and maintaining the same directory structure

Tags: uploads, media, media-library

I've rebuilt an old website from scratch on a fresh install.

On the old (production) website there are over 1000 PDFs and Word docs. These have been uploaded over a 3 year period via `/wp-content/uploads/`. Files are organised by year and month: `/2019/01/filename.pdf`, for example.

The new website has a different sitemap. 301 redirects are in place to direct the old posts/pages to the new.

Many of the files which need migrating are attached to posts/pages on the old website. The majority of these posts/pages no longer exist on the new website.

I need to migrate the PDFs and Word docs over to the new website which currently sits on a staging server.

The main objectives are:

1. Maintain the old file directory structure, e.g. `/2019/01/filename.pdf`.
2. Only migrate documents (PDFs, Word docs, txt files etc). Imagery and video is not required.

What's the best way to achieve this?

I've looked into [WP Migrate DB Pro](https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-migrate-db-pro/pricing/), but it looks like this migrates all media files.

Comment: I haven't tried this myself, but you could simply upload them via FTP/SSH and then use the [Add from Server](https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-from-server/) plugin to let WP know they exist. This will work for all absolute & relative links that exist within your pages, but if somewhere something references them only via their attachment ID, this will break.

Comment: I think this is a great solution. Did you want to post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't worked this way myself, but a possible solution would be:

1. Upload all of the assets via FTP / SSH / ... to the webserver.
2. Import the assets e.g. via [Add From Server](https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-from-server/) plugin.

Doing a quick web search, a lot of tutorials (maybe outdated?) still refer to this plugin for this specific task. It's last update was ~1y ago - but handling of media files shouldn't have changed that much.

Make sure to test it on a staging/dev site before doing anything on production!

If you have absolute & relative links to the assets, they will continue working. If you reference the attachments by their ID, these will likely not work anymore, as the IDs are going to change.